# Explain CSS structure

Tags: html, css

I have found this code in one of the website. Obviously it is CSS style which defines the font family. But i couldn't get this structure. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
font-family: "Open Sans",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

Comment: If you read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) on `font-family` it explains this quite well. **The docs should always be the first place you go when you have a question about code**.

Comment: *The font-family property specifies a list of fonts, from highest priority to lowest* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family

Comment: Strictly speaking the 'docs' for `font-family` would be those at the [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/), rather than Mozilla (however good MDN is); please see: [`font-family`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop) (as well).

Answer (score 2):

First load *Open Sans* font, if not available load *Helvetica*, If *Helvetica* not available load *Arial*, and, if none of them are available load another *sans-serif* font.

**[Docs:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop)**

*The property value is a prioritized list of font family names and/or generic family names. Unlike most other CSS properties, component values are separated by a comma to indicate that they are alternatives:*

```
body { font-family: Gill, Helvetica, sans-serif }
```

***There are two types of font family names:***

```
<family-name>
```

*The name of a font family of choice. In the last example, "Gill" and "Helvetica" are font families.*

```
<generic-family>
```

*In the example above, the last value is a generic family name. The following generic families are defined:*

```
    'serif' (e.g., Times)
    'sans-serif' (e.g., Helvetica)
    'cursive' (e.g., Zapf-Chancery)
    'fantasy' (e.g., Western)
    'monospace' (e.g., Courier)
```

Comment: In some browsers the list will be consulted further should the current font not contain a requested glyph

Answer (score 0):

The browser will try to use the first font in the list, if it's not installed it will go to the next one in the list and so on.